# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: json, ajax, spring-mvc

I am currently trying to implement ajax calls from jsp in Spring MVC.
My ajax call is as below

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/scrapingtoolweb/searchProcess',
                data : formData,
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(response) {
                    alert("success");
                    alert(response.status);
                    },
                    error: function(response) {  
                        alert("error");
                        alert(response.status);
                    }
                });
```

and my Controller code is as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    @ResponseBody
    public List<WipoDataUI> search(@RequestParam String publicationDateFromUI ,@RequestParam String publicationDateToUI) {
    List<WipoDataUI> wipodata = new ArrayList<WipoDataUI>();
    wipodata = searchService.getData(resultData);
    return wipodata;

}
```

When I try to return the response back to jsp it is throwing 500 exception saying

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpMessageNotWritable
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
```

I read few suggestions saying to add jackson binding and I have added that in my servlet xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
   </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Eventhough it is not solving my issue. Can someone please suggest on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to define converters, just add the below dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${fasterxml.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In my code I had `2.8.7` version number for fasterxml libraries.

Comment: I tried different ways. I already have the above mentioned dependency in my pom.xml. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

For me it solved that problem by defining the converter like this:

```
  <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
        <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```